# How to study to reach level B2 in German on my own?

Tags: self-learning, online-learning, german

I have reached level B1 in German with a teacher, but my finances do not allow to continue in the same way.

How could I continue learning on my own to reach level B2 (in the CEFR) through internet resources, and develop my vocabulary?

Comment: I find this question quite broad and maybe opinion-based

Comment: @AnthonyPham The question may be broad in the sense that it does not focus in a specific area or skill (except for highlighting vocabulary at the end), but specific by focusing on moving from B1 to B2 in a given language (German). How would you suggest improving it?

Comment: @ChristopheStrobbe Specifically, it would be better if the OP narrowed down the types of resources and/or the types of learning (i.e grammar, direct, etc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may not be tough for you. Because one who has German B2 level can easily pass TestDaf. But, you need to prepare with a plan of actions and practice more.

There are four sections: 1. Reading, 2. Writing, 3. Listening, 4. Speaking.
**How to prepare?**

Even if you’re not in Germany, there are tons of reputable online preparation courses you can take if you’re not confident in your ability to keep on track or prefer to have live feedback.

3 to 5 hours in a day may need 8-9months of studying very focused. You will also have to good plan of preparation without breaks and the sources to follow. The more practice is the best result always.

If you have a solid learning structure and see your tutor every second day, you should not suffer long.

Speaking Practice with Real People. The speaking section of TestDaF is incredibly awkward. Rather than speaking to a real human being, you’ll be put in a computer room with the other test participants and asked to speak into your microphone for seven exercises.

The same idea as Speaking works for writing practice. I found it incredibly helpful to crank out a few essays written by hand to get a feel for the time constraints. A super nice friend can then go through and destroy your grammar and mistakes. You’ll never make the same mistakes again.

Practice on TestDaF’s site: There are tons of mock exams available for purchase to simulate the real things, but TestDaF’s website includes two for free
You’ll find practice for all four sections along with the audio needed and instructions as they appear on the real exam.

For listening practice, watch movies and media in German on Netflix, YouTube, or other online sites. Turning on the subtitles helps to engrave those new words into your memory and technically isn’t cheating since even the listening section of TestDaF has a written prompt matching the audio.

TestDaF Practice Tests
https://www.testdaf.de/zielgruppen/fuer-teilnehmende/vorbereitung/modellsaetze/
http://www.godaf.de/?url=/de/probe/
http://testdaftipps.blogspot.de/2010/01/mundliche-ausdruck.html
https://www.hueber.de/sixcms/media.php/36/1699-FitTestDaF.pdf
https://www.testdaf.de/teilnehmer/tn-vorbereitung_test.php?id=1
http://www.fabouda.de/testdaf%20training/proben%20testdaf%2020.15/Schreiben.pdf

Training/Tips for the TestDaF
http://deutschtraining.info/course/testdaf-vorbereitung-online/

Vocabulary
http://dl.keywin.org/4/5/459618e94d24dd01480589e44c6d4711.pdf

Comment: You write, "one who has German B2 level can easily pass TestDaf". Do you have a source for that? As far as I know it is a C1 test. I the past few years, I have helped a few Chinese students prepare for it. Level B2 was not sufficient for them to pass that test.

Comment: You can find online resources. The free sources I mentioned above. The more practice will be the best way to pass language proficiency tests.